# Use GraphicsMagick methods depends on dimensions with CollectionFS

Tags: node.js, meteor, graphicsmagick

I am looking for a working way to to use the GM methods in CollectionFS transformWrite function depending o the image size. There is a size method implemented in GM but this works async and so it seems to be not possible to use.

I tried the following:

```
gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).size(function(err, dimensions){
    if (err) {
        console.log('err with getting size:');
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('Result of media_size:');
    console.log(dimensions);
    // here do smth depends on the dimensions ...

    gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).resize('1200', '630').stream().pipe(writeStream);


});
```

When i use the above snippet in the CollectionFS function I get this error:

**Error: gm().stream() or gm().write() with a non-readable stream.**

This seems to be a problem that I use a async function - when removing the async function the upload works perfectly but then I have no access to the dimensions of the uploaded image.

Is there a solution to get the dimensions of the image in a sync way when having just access to `fileObj`, `readStream` & `writeStream` ?

**Edit:**

Thanks Jasper for the hint with the wrapAsync. I tested it and have this code in use:

```
var imgsize;
var img = gm(readStream, fileObj.name());
imgsize = Meteor.wrapAsync(img.size, img);
console.log('call wrapAsync:');
var result;
try {
    result = imgsize();
} catch (e) {
    console.log('Error:');
    console.log(e)
}
console.log('((after imgsize()))');
```

When take a look at the console.logs the script stops after "call wrapAsync" - also there is no error returning so its very difficult to tell whats the problem. I also tried this with the NPM package "imagesize" with `Meteor.wrapAsync(imagesize);` and then `imgsize(readStream)` which causes the same: No console log after "call wrapAsync:".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core of the problem is not the asynchronous behavior of `gm().size()`, but the fact that you use the `readStream` twice. First you use it to get the size of the image, which empties `readStream`. Then you try to use it again to resize but because it has ended, you get an error telling you the stream is non-readable.

I found the solution at the bottom of the gm package's [streams documenation](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm#streams):

> GOTCHA: when working with input streams and any 'identify' operation
>   (size, format, etc), you must pass "{bufferStream: true}" if you also
>   need to convert (write() or stream()) the image afterwards NOTE: this
>   buffers the readStream in memory!

Based on that and the small example below, we can change your code to:

```
gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).size({ bufferStream: true }, function(err, dimensions){
    if (err) {
        console.log('err with getting size:');
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('Result of media_size:');
    console.log(dimensions);
    // here do smth depends on the dimensions ...

    this.resize('1200', '630').stream().pipe(writeStream);
});
```

Inside of the callback, `this` refers to the image you're working on and you can use it to continue your chain.

I tested this in a small sample meteor application, and it works!

Comment: Thanks for the github reference. I will check this tomorrow and give you the information if this worked.

Comment: Too sad: I dont know why but this seems not to be working. After the getSize() step the code stops...no console.log will be executed after this. I tested it and before getSize() I added a console.log(getSize) (returns [function]) but when console.log(getSize());console.log('test');  nothing will be returned.

Comment: Hey Jasper I edited my question maybe this helps you to see what the problem could be ?

Comment: I'm checking this out, will get back to you!

Comment: Ok, I retraced your steps and could reproduce the problem of the function hanging. I banged my head against the wall for a bit but haven't been able to find out why this fails. It's an open mystery. However, while playing around I noticed that your original idea of piping the streams together in the callback did work for me! Turns out your problem wasn't related to the asynchronous behavior, but something else, so I rewrote my answer. Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will be able to test it in about 2 hours - i will let you know! :)

Comment: Thats it! Thanks a lot Jasper Woudenberg.

Comment: How to use crop instead of resize ?